# maven dependency not support when code is pushed to remote server

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, spring, maven

I have a web application which I developed on my local system and it works fine in my local system but when I push it to the remote server I get compilation errors (maven dependency problems) does not load my spring frame work in the remote server. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
 here is my pom.xml

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
   http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.o7planning</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringMVCSecurityXML</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SpringMVCSecurityXML Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>




    <properties>
        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>


    <repositories>
        <!-- Repository for ORACLE JDBC Driver -->
        <repository>
            <id>codelds</id>
            <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring framework START -->
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring framework END -->


        <!-- Spring Security Artifacts - START -->
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Security Artifacts - END -->


   <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jsr303 validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jstl for jsp page -->
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet API -->
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSP API -->
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/jsp-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL JDBC driver -->
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.34</version>
        </dependency>
   <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jsr303 validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>



    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: I am sorry. The error is "cannot find the symbol @" for the request mapping. "error: package org.springframework.stereotype does not exist" "error: package org.srpingframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist"

Comment: Seems your dependencies are OK for resolving those packages. Try to execute "mvn dependency:tree" to check if Maven resolves well all the dependencies.

Comment: With pushing to remote server you mean a CI solution like Jenkins ? If yes check the configuration for used repositories like a corporate repository manager ...I don't know why you give references to mvnrepository.com ? Why not [central](http://search.maven.org)? Apart from that giving repositories in a pom is bad practice just use a repository manager ....

Comment: javac MainController.java 
MainController.java:5: error: package org.springframework.stereotype does not exist
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
                                     ^
MainController.java:6: error: package org.springframework.ui does not exist
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
                             ^
this is how my error looks like. @little Santi I tried mvn dependency:tree and it builds successfully .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errors at compiling mean that some dependencies are missing. However, they are not when compiling in local. I recommend you execute

```
mvn dependency:build-classpath -Dmdep.outputFile=cp.txt
```

on both environments, which will produce a file `cp.txt` containing the list of libraries used for the compilation classpath. Then, for every library included on it, compare the local version with the remote version. If they are not *binary equal*, purge the libraries from the remote repository:

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository
```